# Invalid MEX-file, dlopen() library not loaded

Tags: macos, matlab, opencv, mex, dlopen

With some help, I found that I should compile first. But when I use `mex mexResize.cpp` to compile in Matlab, I get the error `'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found`. I don't know how to solve that yet.

---

The problem is shown below:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/Users/wes/Documents/MATLAB/BACF_toUpload/mexResize.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/wes/Documents/MATLAB/BACF_toUpload/mexResize.mexmaci64, 6): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/wes/Documents/MATLAB/BACF_toUpload/mexResize.mexmaci64
Reason: image not found.
```

I'm using MATLAB_R2017b, Xcode 9.2. I downloaded python3 and installed opencv with python. I don't know if it has something to do with this.

Comment: Did you compile the MEX-file yourself? It seems that it is looking for the OpenCV library in a place where it is not. This can happen if it was compiled on a different computer, or if you moved the OpenCV library after compiling.

Comment: I have found out that I have 'libopencv_core.3.4.dylib' instead of 'libopencv.2.4.dylib'. So what should I do next?

Comment: @Wes get 2.4 ....? Thats the openCV version I assume, just get the one you need. Or compile it yourself, its likely the recompilation would then use 3.4

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you mean using `mex mexResize.cpp` ? Then I got an error says that `'MxArray.hpp' file not found`.  Or try to run `mexResize.mexmaci64` ? Then I got the problem above.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for your advise. But what I really mean is, how to run this program successfully with opencv3 

Comment: And I answered that! recompiling. Once the program is compiled, you can not just change it, its binary code! If the program is lookign for 2.4, the only way to make it change is recompiling, and maybe even that won't do, maybe you need to change part of the source (not sure if it is like this in this case).